# Responsive design for mobile phones looking like mobile app design

Tags: mobile-application, information-architecture, responsive-design

What do you think about the use of a bottom menu in a responsive design ecommerce site for mobile devices, resembling a mobile app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually varies on the device/s. I am using iPhone SE 1st gen, and sites with bottom menus aren't UX-friendly as some browsers have bottom bars too so wrong clicks are highly probable.